# Remove command(rm) in unix?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

There is no file in my directory called a. I used the command "rm a 2>a" to redirect the standard output error to file a. But when I tried the "ls" command, there is no file called a. Can someone explain this?

Comment: voting to move to superuser

Comment: Well ... what happens when you do not redirect? Is anything printed to `stdout`?

Comment: Is this merely an academic question? What's your use case for using the same file name both for deletion and capturing the output?

Answer (score 10):

`2>a` causes the shell to redirect the standard error stream to a file called `a`. This file is created before the command is started. `rm` is then executed. It finds a file called `a` (already created by the shell) and unlinks it.

Comment: Right... the file still exists, so that anything `rm` writes to stderr after calling `unlink` can go into it, but it no longer has its name.  When the process quits, the file finally goes away.

Answer (score 3):

a is created bbefore the rm command executes....its as simple as that!